# nativePHP:: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to install nativePHP package on my fresh new laravel application following the documentation guide on `https://nativephp.com/docs/1/getting-started/installation`
When running the command `php artisan native:serve` I am getting error that `TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform`.
Can anyone help me although nativePHP it would be great if someone can guide me
SO is still not accepting tag for nativePHP

Comment: It's already reported since a couple of hours: https://github.com/NativePHP/electron/issues/18 - Check it and see how you can help there, this will give you the best possible progress.